# could not able to retrive the properties values in eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I created the message.properties file inside my plugin under OSGI-INF/l10n/.

Then I created my Message.java class with the `@Message(contributiURI="").`

Then I injected the message in the class where I am showing the message like follows,

```
public class test{
@Inject
    @Translation
    private Messages message;
//some code
sysout(messages.Test);
//somecode
}
```

Also, I have added following in the MANIFEST.MF file

```
Bundle-Localization: OSGI-INF/l10n/messages
```

after doing all the above. I executed my code and I could not able to get the value from the properties file. it just returns `"!test!"`. Could anyone please tell me what did I miss?

Thanks & Regards,
Chinniah

Comment: What do you have in the `OSGI-INF/l10n` folder?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have kept messages.properties file in OSGI-INF/l10/messages.

Comment: i removed the @Message(contributiURI=""). Now it is working fine.

Comment: I think if the messages.properties file is present in the same plugin where MEssages.java is present, i should not give the @Message(contributiURI="").

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.

Comment: `contributiURI` is wrong - it is `contributionURI`. If missing or blank it looks for the Messages.properties or the Bundle-Localization